# The ${^MATCH} and the /p modifier in perl v24

Tags: perl

The [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) says:

> p
>
> Preserve the string matched such that ${^PREMATCH} , ${^MATCH} , and
>   ${^POSTMATCH} are available for use after matching.
>
> In Perl 5.20 and higher this is ignored. Due to a new copy-on-write
>   mechanism, ${^PREMATCH} , ${^MATCH} , and ${^POSTMATCH} will be
>   available after the match regardless of the modifier.

also the [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html)

> ${^MATCH}
>   This is similar to $& ($MATCH ) except that it does not incur the
>   performance penalty associated with that variable.
>
> In Perl v5.18 and earlier, it is only guaranteed to return a defined 
>   value when the pattern was compiled or executed with the /p modifier. 
>   In Perl v5.20, the /p modifier does nothing, so ${^MATCH} does the same thing as $MATCH .

test:

```
echo 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit ut dicta qui dolores.' |\
 perl -nE 'say ${^MATCH} while m/dolor/g'
```

output: two empty lines (2x `\n`)

but the:

```
echo 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit ut dicta qui dolores.' |\
 perl -nE 'say ${^MATCH} while m/dolor/gp'
```

output:

```
dolor
dolor
```

My perl:

```
$ perl -v

This is perl 5, version 24, subversion 0 (v5.24.0) built for darwin-2level
(with 1 registered patch, see perl -V for more detail)
```

So in the `5.24.0` the `/p` modifier is still needed? Or what me missed?

Comment: I concur with your assessment. Workaround: You could use `$&` (`$MATCH`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is indeed a discrepancy between the code's behaviour and the documented behaviour. Filed a bug report as ticket [RT#131087](https://rt.perl.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=131087).

As a workaround, you can use use `$&` (`$MATCH`).